# Error Paypal REST API (sandbox) 404:"The requested URL /cgi-bin/ppapi was not found on this server."

Tags: paypal

I'm using PHP curl and it is communicating with the server. I'm trying to get a token. I get the following unhelpful response from the paypal sandbox:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /cgi-bin/ppapi was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache Server at api.sandbox.paypal.com Port 443
```

I'm running the code (below) from localhost on my laptop.

/gettoken.php

```
<?php
//header('Content-Type:application/javascript');

$url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/token";
$client_id = "xxx";
$secret = "xxx";

//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();

// set basic auth
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_BASIC);

// set user/password
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,$client_id.":".$secret);

// set header accept
$headers = array('Accept:application/json','Accept-Language:en_US');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);

// set mode to POST
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);

// add post fields (1)
$fields_string = "grant_type=client_credentials";
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
if($result === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

// close curl
curl_close($ch);

// decode result
//var json = json_decode($result, true);
echo('<pre>'.$result.'</pre>');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, the url to the REST service was wrong.. should have been:

```
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
```

At least we know that if you get this error that it is likely the REST endpoint url is probably wrong.